# making map coordinates(lan,& long)storing in sqlite database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, sqlite, mkmapview

how to created an application that records a series of longitude and latitude values in a SQLite database and display them as a coloured track on a MapActivity.

I need help. How can store the map coordinates in sqlite database  and display like journey details in table .For example I have done one journey from  mumbai to Pune .Then how can store the data into database that can available for future reference .when user click on journey name  it should give all details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new to Sqlite Then look into this class for data base 
Create two database file as the following

---->>>>
Database.h

Write the following code in this file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <sqlite3.h>


@interface DataBase : NSObject {

    sqlite3 *database;

}

+(DataBase *) shareDataBase;

-(BOOL) createDataBase:(NSString *)DataBaseName;

-(NSString*) GetDatabasePath:(NSString *)database;

-(NSMutableArray *) getAllDataForQuery:(NSString *)sql  forDatabase:(NSString *)database;
-(void) inseryQuery:(NSString *) insertSql forDatabase:(NSString *)database1;
-(void) deleteQuery:(NSString *) deleteSql forDatabase:(NSString *)database1;
-(void) updateQuery:(NSString *) updateSql forDatabase:(NSString *)database1;

@end
```

---->>>>
    Database.m

Write the following code in this file

```
#import "DataBase.h"


@implementation DataBase

static DataBase *SampleDataBase =nil;


+(DataBase*) shareDataBase{

    if(!SampleDataBase){
        SampleDataBase = [[DataBase alloc] init];
    }

    return SampleDataBase;

}


-(NSString *) GetDatabasePath:(NSString *)database1{


    [self createDataBase:database1];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:database1];
}


-(BOOL) createDataBase:(NSString *)DataBaseName{
    BOOL success; 

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:DataBaseName];

    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
    if (success) return success;
    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:DataBaseName];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];

    if (!success) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!!!" message:@"Failed to create writable database" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

    }
    return success;
}



-(NSMutableArray *) getAllDataForQuery:(NSString *)sql  forDatabase:(NSString *)database1{

    sqlite3_stmt *statement = nil ;

    NSString *path = [self GetDatabasePath:database1];

    NSMutableArray *alldata;
    alldata = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if(sqlite3_open([path UTF8String],&database) == SQLITE_OK )
    {
        NSString *query = sql;

        if((sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,[query UTF8String],-1, &statement, NULL)) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {   

                NSMutableDictionary *currentRow = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

                int count = sqlite3_column_count(statement);

                for (int i=0; i < count; i++) {

                    char *name = (char*) sqlite3_column_name(statement, i);
                    char *data = (char*) sqlite3_column_text(statement, i);

                    NSString *columnData;
                    NSString *columnName = [NSString stringWithCString:name encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


                    if(data != nil)
                        columnData = [NSString stringWithCString:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                    else {
                        columnData = @"";
                    }

                    [currentRow setObject:columnData forKey:columnName];
                }

                [alldata addObject:currentRow];
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement); 
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);

    return alldata;

}

-(void) inseryQuery:(NSString *) insertSql forDatabase:(NSString *)database1{

    sqlite3_stmt *statement = nil ;

    NSString *path = [self GetDatabasePath:database1];

    if(sqlite3_open([path UTF8String],&database) == SQLITE_OK )
    {
        if((sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,[insertSql UTF8String],-1, &statement, NULL)) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_OK){
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement); 
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);

}

-(void) updateQuery:(NSString *) updateSql forDatabase:(NSString *)database1{

    sqlite3_stmt *statement = nil ;

    NSString *path = [self GetDatabasePath:database1];

    if(sqlite3_open([path UTF8String],&database) == SQLITE_OK )
    {
        if((sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,[updateSql UTF8String],-1, &statement, NULL)) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_OK){
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement); 
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);

}

-(void) deleteQuery:(NSString *) deleteSql forDatabase:(NSString *)database1{

    sqlite3_stmt *statement = nil ;

    NSString *path = [self GetDatabasePath:database1];

    if(sqlite3_open([path UTF8String],&database) == SQLITE_OK )
    {
        if((sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,[deleteSql UTF8String],-1, &statement, NULL)) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_OK){
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement); 
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);

}



@end
```

Now to get data use the following code

```
NSString *sql = @"select * from UserInfo"; <br>
userInfo = [[DataBase shareDataBase] getAllDataForQuery:sql forDatabase:@"Sample.db"];
```

It will return array of all the row in form of NSDictionary.

To add new record use the following code

```
NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into userInfo values ('city','name','phone')"];
[[DataBase shareDataBase] inseryQuery:sql forDatabase:@"Sample.db"];
```

In the same way there is also method to update and delete record.

so This is the best example I have seen we just need to call one method to for fetch, insert , update or delete.

Thanks for seeing the question,

Comment: Don't forget to import library sqlite3 from the existing framework

Comment: I know this BUt how can i store the  coordinter(lan,long) into database

Comment: There are lots of way to do this. One of the way that i have make is whenever user make journey create new journey in journey table or any thing else to store that journey. and to store (lat,long) create some txt file and store location info in form of XML or JSON. and give reference of file in the database. JSON is the faster than XML to parse the date.

Comment: how can i store location in from of json . And where can i get this location ?

Comment: I don't understand why every time my a/c closed by team please open a/c give me hint how can i open it this user a/c

Comment: how i store c.latitude,c.longitude this into the sqlite database -(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c { coordinate = c; NSLog(@"%f,%f",c.latitude,c.longitude); return s

Comment: I already told you don't store location info in sqlite database because when the database increase it consume more time to fetch the location info for particular travel. Store in txt file using some format and store that file name in sqlite.

Comment: how can store this into txt( coordinate = c; NSLog(@"%f,%f",c.latitude,c.longitude)And how can store into sqlite database

Comment: @kunal can you please help me to understand .How can I write  the (c.latitude,c.longitu) in the text file and how can i store this into and sqlite how can i use this please help me out Kunal

Comment: @ scott. First of all, Do you know how to create file in iphone ?

Comment: check my new answer that i have post for write location info in json format in txt file

Comment: @kunal what happen friend .Do you have hints ?to Slove this

Comment: @kunal Yes I didn't know how to create file for storing lan,long dynamically in iphone And how can call and store this file in sqlite

Comment: @kunal what happen friend really I need help

Answer (score 1):

To get location import corelocation framework  in your project.
follow this link

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LocateMe/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007801     to get sample for getting location.

This is the format to set location in  json

[{"Longitude":"45.2655","Latitude":"23.2655"},{"Longitude":"45.2655","Latitude":"23.2655"},{"Longitude":"45.2655","Latitude":"23.2655"}]

Thanks.

Comment: how i store c.latitude,c.longitude this into the sqlite database      -(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c
{
 coordinate = c;
 NSLog(@"%f,%f",c.latitude,c.longitude);
 return self;
}

Comment: I already told you don't store location info in sqlite database because when the database increase it consume more time to fetch the location info for particular travel. Store in txt file using some format and store that file name in sqlite.

Comment: How can I store this(c.latitude,c.longitude) in txt file and then how can store this txt file into the sqlite then how can use this file into map

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a table with fields ...... *Source,Destination,SourceLat,SourceLong,DestinationLat,DestinationLong*....... and in this you will pass

```
Source - Mumbai,(or other) - text - varchar type
Destinatino - Pune, (or other) -text - varchar type
SourceLat - coordinate.latitude; - number with decimal precison upto 10 points.
SourceLong - coordinate.longitude - number with decimal precison upto 10 points.
DestinationLat - coordinate.latitude; - number with decimal precison upto 10 points.
DestinationLong - coordinate.longitude - number with decimal precison upto 10 points.
```

Thanks,

Comment: I am new for sqlite database can you PLease explain in detail .IF I create this then how can I store this in to database And how can i display under tableview

Comment: http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/  ....... this tutorial will help you in this...... thanks,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184861/how-to-insert-data-to-sqlite-database-in-iphone

Comment: but my values come Dynamically (lan,long).Than how can i store this Dynamic values into sqlite

Comment: When you will get your direction data, you need to simply call insert operation..... yes, you will have to write it and pass you direction lat/long in it.......

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create object of NSMutableArray *arrayOflocation; in .h file,

Then in you locationUpdate method write the following code

```
NSMutableDictionary *LocationDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[LocationDic setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",c.latitude] forKey:@"Latitude"];
[LocationDic setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",c.longitude] forKey:@"Longitude"];

[arrayOflocation addObject:LocationDic];
```

now when you save the trip you need to create the string for the json format for that you need to use json API you can get it using google easily . write the following code when you want to save the string in file.

```
NSString *dataString = [arrayOflocation JSONRepresentation];
//// code to write dataString in txt file.
```

and at finally need to store the file name in sqlite along with other detail for the trip.

Comment: I didn't get you. Please can you explain me more ? (1)Is this necessary to use  json or xml for writing data into file ?(2)What is file name in this how can store into sqlite (3)how to write select stement for getting this file .thanks for replay

Comment: I am not understand what you didn't get . It is very simple and easy, 1 ) it is not necessary to use xml or json format but is is batter to parse . 2) file name is also be anything but i suggest to give the name of the trip which your has made . 3) for selecting the name of the file from data base you need to give the simple sql query as normally we give.

Comment: I just need Lan,long must store in the  sqlite .But you say that (store this lan,long into the file and then store this file into the sqlite ).That's why I ask you how to do that .At that time i didn't get and that's why ask you how do that.

Comment: If you want to store Lat, Long  directly in sqlite then you can store it, but now just take simple look on this scenario. if you take lat /long at every 5 second the user make trip of 1 hour then there are 12 * 60  row for one trip that

Comment: If you want to store Lat, Long  directly in sqlite then you can store it, but now just take simple look on this scenario. if you take lat /long at every 5 second the user make trip of 1 hour then there are 720 (60 * 60 / 5) row for one trip that if user make a trip for every day then after one month there are 21600(720 * 30) now for getting trip data for particular trip your query need to search in this much of data. but if you work as per my advise there are only 30 row for each trip and you will get the file name which has only data for that trip which you what to select.

Comment: Yes I get .I didn't know how to create file for storing lan,long dynamically in iphone And how can call and store this file in sqlit

Comment: Thanks friend can you help me to create the file and storing lan and loang into this file and storing and retrieving this file  from sqlite

Comment: @kunal you have any hint for creating the file for storing this lan, and long