# How to insert data in SQL Lite in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios10

I am trying to insert the value of 2 text box which are user id and password.
But i am not getting any error or exception.

Code as follows:

I have taken 2 textbook and i am doing it on click of that button.

This is my .m file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "sqlite3.h"
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>
NSString *databasePath;
 NSString *docsDir;
static sqlite3 *database = nil;
static sqlite3_stmt *statement = nil;
@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize  status,status2;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   }

- (IBAction)saveData:(id)sender{

    databasePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"ButterFly2BE" ofType:@"db"];
  NSString *p=@"PAss";
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &adddata) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                               @"INSERT INTO tblUser (UserId,Password,Description) VALUES(\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")"
                                , _username.text, _password.text, p];


            const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
             sqlite3_prepare_v2(adddata, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL);
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
                {
                        status.text = @"Contact added";
                       // status.text = @"";
                    status2.text = @"";
                   // phone.text = @"";
                } else {
            status.text = @"Failed to add contact";
            }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(adddata);
}
    }
@end
```

Comment: What problem you are facing? The data is not inserted...right? Just log the sql query and open the database using [DB browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/).

Comment: Refer this link you will find your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17080018/use-and-access-existing-sqlite-database-on-ios/39536484#39536484

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert data into a SQLite database in iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184861/how-to-insert-data-into-a-sqlite-database-in-iphone)

Answer (score 2):

The insertion failed because you used the database stored in the app bundle directly.

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ButterFly2BE" ofType:@"db"]
```

[Files in the app bundle are read only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853014/file-write-with-nsbundle-mainbundle-fails). You need to first [copy the database elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491238/how-to-copy-sqlite-database-when-application-is-launched-in-ios) e.g. the Documents folder before opening it.

---

Note that you should use [the `sqlite3_bind_xxxx` functions](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) instead of `-stringWithFormat:` because the latter exposes you to [SQL injection attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017688/why-we-do-sqlitecommand-parameters-add-while-we-can-use-string-format-to-compos).

```
sqlite3_prepare_v2(adddata, 
                   "INSERT INTO tblUser (UserId, Password, Description) VALUES (?, ?, ?);",
                   -1, &statement, NULL);
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, _username.text.UTF8String, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, _password.text.UTF8String, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, p.UTF8String, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
    ...
```